# Why does sexual promiscuity not lead to the three lower realms?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I posted this in [an answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/33498/254):

> Regardless, random acts of performing consensual oral sex outside of committed relationships leads to 'rebirth' in the hungry ghost
>   (addiction), animal (shamelessness) & hell (suffering) realms. It is
>   quite obvious the significant amount Western women over 40 years of
>   age using
>   antidepressants is probably largely due to their former sexual
>   promiscuity & broken relationships.

Then I read [the following comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/33497/is-it-forbidden-in-thai-buddhist-religion-for-a-woman-to-perform-consensual-oral#comment56513_33498) to the above:

> I am downvoting this answer with regards to overgeneralizations that
>   doesn't reflect buddhism .

Why does sexual promiscuity not lead to the three lower realms?

Also, why are sex addiction, wrong views, chronic loneliness, chronic anxiety, loss of self-esteem, depression & chronic sadness not "lower realms"?

Why does the 1st comment not reflect Buddhism?

Comment: Hi DD! I really expect to keep this conversation in the kindest way possible, without passive-agression or subtle insults to each other. About the question, I don't have a proper answer, but in my opinion, the assumption of depression because mostly about sexual promiscuity and broken relationships might be an overgeneralization. There might be lot of other, even more predominant causes for insatisfaction in women of that age, but as I don't have any study or evidence at hand, I'm not in a place to say what those causes and factors might be. Kind regards!

Answer (score 2):

**Why does the 1st comment not reflect Buddhism?**

Consider, "Shark attacks cause of loss of limb. It's quite obvious the significant number of people without limbs is probably largely due to shark attacks."

That's some theory but I'm pretty sure that it's diabetes (or, in a few areas, land mines) that's the more common reason for loss of limb.

I guess that's what the OP meant, by "over-generalisation".

I presume there are other reasons for antidepressants;
they say common [causes of depression](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/clinical-depression/causes/) include:

> For some people, an upsetting or stressful life event, such as bereavement, divorce, illness, redundancy and job or money worries, can be the cause.

... also ...

> - Stressful events
> - Personality
> - Family history
> - Giving birth
> - Loneliness
> - Alcohol and drugs
> - Illness

If it were me rather than you diagnosing a cause (not that I should, especially), I'd suggest e.g. perhaps a lack of kindness or generosity, possibly a lack of physical exercise, maybe system social oppression (sexism) -- as well as society's ignoring, failing to teach, the causes of happiness and unhappiness.

Possibly you've seen some examples (of anti-depressant use) in your personal life, and attribute that (unhappiness) to broken relationships. I don't think it's kind to generalise to the population at large -- people might experience "broken relationships" even though they were never promiscuous, or become depressed for other reasons. You might to be tempted to say, "they must have done something wrong", but I'd fear to engage in "victim blaming" and "adding insult to injury" and general misogyny.

Also it might useful as a cautionary tale ("don't be promiscuous, kids, or you'll become depressed!") -- but I don't see it as an especially "Buddhist" diagnosis -- because something I admire of Buddhist doctrine is that it's prescriptive and actionable. So it isn't ...

- You were bad in the past so now you're in hell, your fault

... and instead it's ...

- The present and future aren't predetermined by the past, your action in the present is effective